# restrict scientific notation to certain powers of 10

Tags: python-3.x

For engineering units I usually only want to print in scientific notation with powers that correspond to mu (10^-6), milli (10^-3), kilo (10^3), mega (10^6), etc. Here is an example of what I would like to print:

```
def number_range(num):
    if abs(num) < 1e-3:
        return '{:.2f}u'.format(num*1e6)     
    elif abs(num) < 0:
        return '{:2f}m'.format(num*1e3)
    elif abs(num) < 1e3:
        return '{:.2f}'.format(num)
    elif abs(num) < 1e6:
        return '{:.2f}k'.format(num*1e-3)   
    elif abs(num) < 1e9:
        return '{:.2f}M'.format(num*1e-6)
```

Or instead of the letter prefixes u, m, k, M, print like the format specifier e,E would, but only have it use powers of 10 that are multiples of 3: 1e-6, 1e-3, 1e3, 1e6, etc. Is there a built in way or do I need to implement this myself, like I've started to?

Comment: It seems that your code wouldn't work as it is. Looks like the second condition should be abs(num) < 1. Also, it appears your code assumes numbers always are in SI (International System of Units) as opposed to CGS for example. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Good catch, thanks. The second condition should be 1. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is a builtin way to do that. But, here is my suggestion:

```
def MyFormat(num, unit=''):
    '''

    Parameters
    ----------
    num : a floating point number to format in a returned string

    unit : string, optional
        Unit of measure e.g, volts, amps, meters. 
        The default is ''.

    Returns
    -------
    A string formatted accordingly, in scientific notation powers of
    10 only in multiples of 3, and if units is provided, prefixes and the
    unit are used. 

    '''
    if unit != '':
        if abs(num) < 1e-3:
            return '{:.2f} u{}'.format(num*1e6, unit)     
        elif abs(num) < 1:
            return '{:.2f} m{}'.format(num*1e3, unit)
        elif abs(num) < 1e3:
            return '{:.2f} {}'.format(num, unit)
        elif abs(num) < 1e6:
            return '{:.2f} k{}'.format(num*1e-3, unit)   
        elif abs(num) < 1e9:
            return '{:.2f} M{}'.format(num*1e-6, unit)
    else:
        if abs(num) < 1e-3:
            return '{:.2f}e-6'.format(num*1e6)     
        elif abs(num) < 1:
            return '{:.2f}e-3'.format(num*1e3)
        elif abs(num) < 1e3:
            return '{:.2f}'.format(num)
        elif abs(num) < 1e6:
            return '{:.2f}e3'.format(num*1e-3)   
        elif abs(num) < 1e9:
            return '{:.2f}e6'.format(num*1e-6)
```